# Adjust margins for long table on a landscape page

Tags: margins, longtable, landscape

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\section{My First Section}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{2in} |>{}m{3.5in} | >{}m{0.8in}| >{}m{0.3in} |>{}m{0.7in} |} \hline
    \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Cited-by} \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Now I would like to increase the margins, such that more rows will fit on the page. Normally I would use:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}
...
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

But with landscape orientation this does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED answer:

Here, I use the `geometry` package to temporarily reset the page dimensions and then reset them back after the table.  In this way, the `longtable` should still be able to break across pages, unlike my original solution below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
Where are the old margins
\newgeometry{margin=4cm}
\begin{landscape}
\section{My First Section}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{2in} |>{}m{3.5in} | >{}m{0.8in}| >{}m{0.3in} |>{}m{0.7in} |} \hline
    \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Cited-by} \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
Where are the new margins?
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ORIGINAL answer:

Here, I tried to expand leftward and rightward symmetrically, and not move the page number.

Of course, I should point out that it is a bit incongruous to both use `longtable` and then try to squeeze it onto one page.  The solution here effectively will nullify the multipage nature of `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{\section{My First Section}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{2in} |>{}m{3.5in} | >{}m{0.8in}| >{}m{0.3in} |>{}m{0.7in} |} \hline
    \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Cited-by} \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}}
\begin{landscape}
\makebox[4.2in]{\smash{\raisebox{-12.9cm}{\smash{\box0}}}}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely it can not be?, a whole document without loading a package with the letters `stack` somewhere in its name:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  LOL!  Perhaps I should add it to the preamble for old time's sake

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Of course, you rightly jest about my ignorance when it comes to LaTeX.  As they say, "if your only tool is a hammer, then eventually every problem begins looking like a nail."  You can substitute "stackengine" and "stack" as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX complains a bit but:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\addtolength\textwidth{5cm}
\begin{landscape}

\section{My First Section}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{2in} |>{}m{3.5in} | >{}m{0.8in}| >{}m{0.3in} |>{}m{0.7in} |} \hline
    \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Cited-by} \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
    F.M.~Cardullo, A.V.~Ercole, J.A.~Houck, L.C.~Kelly &
    {A}lgorithm for {S}imulating {A}tmospheric {T}urbulence and {A}eroelastic {E}ffects on {S}imulator {M}otion {S}ystems &
    techreport &
    2012 & 
    0 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I misreading it, or did your page number shift and you violated the right margin, while leaving the left intact?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No I did all those things:-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes "violated" makes it sound bad but it is not so different from `\enlargethispage` which always steals space from the bottom, never the top.

Comment: Perhaps "asymmetrically enhanced the margin" would sound cushier.  Please accept my apologies :^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes apology accepted:-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it might possible to "steal" space equally from the left and right margin?

Comment: @Pietair as for any page you could locally fiddle with topmargin to move things up (ie to the left)

Comment: Thanks, I used \vspace*{-10\baselineskip}, but this only works at the first page. Can I extend this over multiple pages?

Comment: @Pietair try with `\addtolength\textwidth{5cm}\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-2.5cm}`