# Adjust textwidth for multi-page landscape table

Tags: pdftex, longtable, landscape, classicthesis

I'm using pdflatex and the classicthesis package to write and format my thesis. A narrow text width and broad margins (for margin paragraphs) are used in this layout.

Using this general page layout, I now want to insert a multi-page landscape table and would like to allow the table to span the whole page, i.e. use the margins to include a few more rows in the table. How can I achieve that?

I tried using "newgeometry" provided by the geometry package (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171825/adjust-margins-for-long-table-on-a-landscape-page/)) but if I do that (outside of the landscape environment), also the page number and header position change (which I don't want).

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,fontsize=12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[inner=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=25mm,textwidth=120mm,%
           marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A chapter}
        This is the page layout...
    \section{A section}
..with a reference to table \ref{tab:long}... \graffito{..and comments in the margins.}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{landscape} 
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}    

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}crrrrrrrrrr} 
    \caption[]{\normalsize First caption\footnotemark{}.\label{tab:long}}\\[10pt]
  \toprule
Item number&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \caption{Table caption (continued)}\\[10pt]
\toprule 
Item number&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

A&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
B&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
C&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
D&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
E&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
F&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
G&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
H&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
I&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
J&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
K&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
L&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
M&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
N&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
O&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
P&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
Q&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
R&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
S&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
T&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
U&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
V&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
W&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
X&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
Y&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
Z&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
\bottomrule
\footnotetext{Also, I want to have a footnote to the first table caption that is placed after the last segment of the table.} 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

My original table spans four pages and I want to reduce it to three.
I hope that somebody will be able to help me!

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the header position doesn't change:

```
\documentclass[twoside,fontsize=12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[beramono,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[inner=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=25mm,textwidth=120mm,%
           marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=40mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{A chapter}
        This is the page layout...
    \section{A section}
..with a reference to table \ref{tab:long}... \graffito{..and comments in the margins.}

\lipsum[1]
\newgeometry{textwidth = 160mm}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}\hskip 4cm}}
\begin{landscape}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c*{10}{r}}
    \caption[]{\normalsize First caption\footnotemark{}.\label{tab:long}}\\[10pt]
  \toprule
Item number&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \caption{Table caption (continued)}\\[10pt]
\toprule
Item number&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
\midrule
\endhead

A&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
B&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
C&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
D&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
E&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
F&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
G&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
H&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
I&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
J&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
K&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
L&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
M&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
N&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
O&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
P&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
Q&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
R&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
S&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
T&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
U&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
V&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
W&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
X&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
Y&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\[20pt]
Z&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---&---\\
\bottomrule
\footnotetext{Also, I want to have a footnote to the first table caption that is placed after the last segment of the table.}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does change. If you add another page after the table you will see that the header "2 A CHAPTER" and the one on the next left page "4 A CHAPTER" are in very different horizontal positions. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Chrenk, your claims aren't true. answer provide exactly what you ask in your question.

Comment: they are true - if I try to use this "solution" in my code the page numbers and chapter headings are moved towards the border of the page as well.

Comment: I've updated the code to satisfy the requirement. The headers on odd pages alone have to be modified. This is done through a modified`\rohead` command.