# ClassicThesis: Widen Content Area to include Margin

Tags: margins, classicthesis

I am typesetting my thesis with `ClassicThesis` and am super happy with the narrow content area and the wide margins. However, I need to include some large tables in the appendix and would like them to take up the space reserved for the margin in addition to the actual content space.

What is the best way to set this up? I still want the alternating page layout and need the changes to affect only one section of the appendix.

```
\documentclass[ twoside,headinclude,footinclude,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}
\blindtext[7]

\chapter{Appendix}
\blindtext[3]

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{c|p{0.9\linewidth}}
ID & Descriptors \\ \hline
\endhead
1 & \blindtext \\
2 & \blindtext \\
3 & \blindtext \\
4 & \blindtext \\
5 & \blindtext \\
6 & \blindtext \\
7 & \blindtext \\
8 & \blindtext \\
9 & \blindtext \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

When looking at it in the original portrait orientation I want the table to extend further to the left on its first and last page, and further to the right on the second page. When looking at it in landscape mode this will mean height to place rows in. This should be achieved while not interfering with the layout of the "Intro" chapter.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: this might be helpful: [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do not want it to expand beyond the content area equally on both sides, but only in the direction of the (larger) outside margin.

Comment: you mean I think left and right in the original portrait orientation (so up and down when viewing the landscape table)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle exactly. I have added that to my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `geometry` package and change the margins of the pages that your `longtable` goes on. It doesn't float anyway.
Before you switch to the `landscape` mode, just issue a `\newgeometry` command. In the example below, I set all the margins to an extreme .5cm for illustration purposes, but of course you can also set all margins as you wish, like so:
`\newgeometry{top = 3cm, outer = 1cm, bottom = 3cm, inner = 1cm}`.
When you're done with inserting the tables, just change the margins back to your original values issuing `\newgeometry` again.

```
\documentclass[ twoside,headinclude,footinclude,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}
\blindtext[7]

\chapter{Appendix}

\blindtext[3]

\newgeometry{margin=.5cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{c|p{0.9\linewidth}}

ID & Descriptors \\ \hline
\endhead
1 & \blindtext \\
2 & \blindtext \\
3 & \blindtext \\
4 & \blindtext \\
5 & \blindtext \\
6 & \blindtext \\
7 & \blindtext \\
8 & \blindtext \\
9 & \blindtext \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `left` or `outer` indeed works well with the `twoside` option, but please note that this approach also influences the positioning of the headers.

Comment: duh! you're right, it does change the headers. And of course, for `twoside` `inner/outer` should be used instead of `left/right`. I changed that. My first attempt was to use a starred * variant, but it doesn't seem to exist for `longtable` ...

Comment: I might have to use something like that, but I would really prefer an approach that does not mess up the headers.

Comment: @FAS: I've been trying and googling for a while now, found this old question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171825/adjust-margins-for-long-table-on-a-landscape-page also using geometry. Could you split your `longtable` manually at the pagebreaks, and use the tabular environment instead? There are some variants that extend into the margin (I'm not sure if they work with `landscape` though).

Comment: @Wiebke no, splitting them by hand is not really an option. There are quite a few tables, so I would like to avoid that.

Comment: For now I replicated the original margins generated by ClassicThesis for my settings (11pt, a4paper) using geometry, change the textwidth for the tables, and revert it afterwards. While the textwidth is changed I manually adapt the headers to include `hskip`s to push the page numbers back to their old positin.